# Grep Database from db2diag.log string

Tags: sed, grep

I want to get the Database String from Part EDUNAME: db2agent (**PRD**)

My first try does not work ;-)

```
sed 's/.*EDUNAME: .* (//' | sed 's/).*FUNCTION.*//
```

Output:

```
2016-02-16-15.29.08.030467+060 I11738607E972         LEVEL: Error PID 
: 28641                TID : 46912874997504  PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst               NODE : 000            DB   : PRD
APPHDL  : 0-25656              APPID: *LOCAL.db2t08.160216144150
AUTHID  : DB2ISNT              HOSTNAME: UNIX1 
EDUID   : 44342                EDUNAME: db2agent (PRD) 0 
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv,
sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:1700 MESSAGE : Severe TERMINATE err at
nest lvl 1, in SQL from rtn
          SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS: DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes  sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136  
sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0  sqlerrmc:  sqlerrp : SQLRRRCP  sqlerrd :
(1) 0x80040003      (2) 0x00000003      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0xFFFFFE0C      (6) 0x00000000  sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)  sqlstate: 55032
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: so you want to extract this string=`EDUNAME: db2agent (PRD) 0` .. right?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean `DB : PRD` is not present when it is part of the message...?

Comment: Is "Output:" above the expected output you do want or the output you currently get that you don't want? In any case - post concise, testable, sample input and the expected output you want given that input. Do not assume we know what a `db2diag.log Message` is unless you only want help from `db2` experts and not from experts in sed or other tools.

Comment: You are right. So I changed the post ;-) I want only the Database Name (PRD)

Comment: Can you say what you are *actually* trying to achieve?  I get you want to know the database name, but I'm not clear why you aren't using the `DB` field.  You may also want to investigate the `db2diag` utility for searching and formatting records from `db2diag.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *GNU* `grep`, you can do the following:

```
 $ grep -Po ' EDUNAME: db2agent \(\K[^)]+' file
 PRD
```

- `-P` actives support for PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions)
- `-o` only outputs what the regex matched.
- `\K` inside the regex drops everything matched so far.
- `[^)]+` then captures everything before the closing `)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat in
2011-01-10-12.10.13.923352-300 I74680A573 LEVEL: Warning
PID : 1234 TID : 100 PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1 NODE : 000 DB : SAMPLE
APPHDL : 0-33648 APPID: 192.168.1.1.50234.11022217100
AUTHID : DB2INST1
EDUID : 608 EDUNAME: db2agent (SAMPLE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, routine_infrastructure, sqlerMasterThreadReq,
probe:89
MESSAGE : FMP reported it could not create a new thread
DATA #1 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x000000020210F180 : 0000 0C05 ....

$ sed -n '/.* EDUNAME: \([^ ]*\).*/s//\1/p' in
db2agent
```

The `-n` switch to `sed` says to skip automatic printing.  The regular expression captures a non-space sequence after `EDUNAME:`.  If the regular expression matches, the `s//\1/p` reuses the prior regex, replaces the match with the first capture and prints the result.

Or maybe you want the next word:

```
$ sed -n '/.* EDUNAME: [^ ]* (\([^ ]*\)).*/s//\1/p' in                                                                                                     
SAMPLE
```

Comment: Thank you, that also worsk well.